# Parse Cloud Code Push Notifications

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification

I have a Class "Storybaord" and there are two instances of when to send a Push Notification.

1. A user likes a post - `[postObject addUniqueObject: [PFUser currentUser] forKey:@"likes"];`
2. A user comments on a post - `[postObject addUniqueObject: self.comment forKey:@"comments"];`

In my cloud code I use `Parse.Cloud.afterSave` but I am unsure of how to distinguish between the two, and also determine if they even happen, because there are other occasions of saving the `postObject` without needing to send a push.

**Cloud Code:**

```
Parse.Cloud.afterSave("Storyboard", function(request){
    var user = Parse.User.current();
    var postUser = request.object.get('userId');

    var pushQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
    pushQuery.equalTo ('userId', postUser);

    Parse.Push.send({
            where: pushQuery,
            data: {
                alert: "Liked Your Post"
                }
                    }, {
                    success: function(){

                    },
                    error: function(){

                    }
            });
    });
```

Comment: So your using client-side code to perform the object updates but cloud code to send a push? You will have to tell if client-side to perform a cloud function with parameters for the push or simply push the notification client-side. Either way is done within the `postObject` client-side. Would you like an example answer for a client side or are you dead-set on cloud push?

Comment: @soulshined Well right now push notifications are sent client side, but from what i have read, it is a security issue. So, I am trying to switch over to cloud code to send push notifications.

Comment: So then, create a cloud code function for when a user likes a `postObject` and if successfully saved, send a push. Then create a separate cloud code function for the comment and send a push within that function. Essentially just like you would client side. No reason to create a conditional statement when it can all be handled in responses or call backs

Comment: @soulshined Yes understood. Thats what I'm trying to do but this is my first time writing cloud code and am confused what to call to distinguish which is which.

Comment: @soulshined something with `Parse.Op.AddUnique()`?

Comment: I see @Peter I'll post an answer tomorrow after work if you don't get one by then. It's bed time here, sorry for the tease

Comment: No my example is instead of creating the object in client-side create the object in cloud code, then simultaneously send a push according to the response

Comment: @soulshined haha you tease me too much. Thanks for the help, tomorrow hopefully ill get lucky. Good night

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your insistent on sending the push via cloud code, all you have to do is set a conditional statement client-side and act accordingly, that way you can opt to send or not according to your needs, since you mentioned something about selectively sending pushing:

```
if (self.likeButton.isSelected) {
    [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"alertAuthor" withParameters:@{@"message", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ liked your post!", [PFUser currentUser].username]}
} 

if (self.commentEntered) {
    [PFCloud callFunctionInBackground:@"alertAuthor" withParameters:@{@"message", [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ commented on your post!", [PFUser currentUser].username]}
}
```

And simply send a push using the parameters via cloud code:

```
Parse.Cloud.define("alertAuthor", function(request,response){
  var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
  var message = request.params.message;
  query.equalTo('username', 'postUser');

  Parse.Push.send({
    where: query,
    data : { 
      alert: message,
      badge: "Increment",
      sound: "",
    }
    }, {
    success: function() {
    //Success
    },
    error: function(error) {
    //Oops
    }
  });
});
```